# access chrome extension only if logged in on webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am complete my chrome extension, however, I want to create a function that when first opening the popup window, it will ask you to login or register. If you clicked "login," then it will take you to my websites login page. Once you logged in, the user will gain access to the content of my chrome extension.

Is this possible to do, if so, how would I attempt to do such?

Ultimately, I want my extension to be used by members, who paid, on my website.

Comment: You could use localstorage in the user's browser for saving / reading the authentication data. here's an example: [link](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/implementing-login-case-using-localstorage-and-sessionstorage-bfddce5d2198)

Comment: thats like exactly what I need, thanks. Quick question: Do you know if the user will remained logged into the extension, even when user closes chromes? @HJEC

Comment: I haven't worked with building extensions before, but if it's anything like your usual web tech, if the users data is saved in localstorage, then you can check their credentials the next time they open the browser and log them in again. If you use session storage then they will be logged out whenever they close the browser etc